# Break lines and wrapping in auto formatting of Visual Studio with ReSharper

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, architecture, resharper

I'm working in a C# project and using Visual Studio 2012. When Visual Studio tries to format my code, it breaks lines and make my code look difficult to read. The original code (what looks pretty nice to read for me and my team):

```
if (list.Any(x => x.Type == (int) EnumType.Customer))
{

}
```

And when Visual Studio tries to format:

```
if (
    list.Any(
        x => x.Type ==
                (int) EnumType.Customer))
{
  // Other break codes
}
```

There are a lot of other parts where it is breaking my code. I like auto formatting for some parts, but my question is: Is there a way to disable this break lines from auto formatting in Visual Studio?*

PS: I also have ReSharper installed.

Comment: This doesn't look like any sort of default code formatting that Visual Studio does. Do you have an extension installed that may be changing how code gets auto-formatted?

Comment: Well, I have resharper installed. Maybe it is doing by resharpers. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Solution for long lines:

ReSharper, menu *Options* → *Code Editing* → *C#* → *Formatting Style* → *Line Breaks And Wrapping*.

And disable *Wrap long lines*:

[image]

And it really makes me crazy!

Comment: Nice to see Resharper in action! :D ;) <3

Comment: Option is now under Resharper > Options... > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping

Comment: plus 1 - "And it really makes me crazy."

Comment: @Felipe Oriani LIfe Saver

Answer (score 2):

In ReSharper's settings, in the *Languages* section, you can change the formatting style of your C# code. The option you're looking to disable is something along the lines of "Indent anonymous method body." You can also look through the options to further customize the formatting style to your preference.

Comment: Thank you Adam, but I found the solution in Reshaper Configs for long lines (my case).