# How to remove all code line breaks in VS 2017 C# text editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I assume, I have accidentally set up some VS2017 automatic C#  text formatting options and my code was automatically formatted. As a result, all long lines were broken into two or more lines. It looks almost like all wrapped up lines in text editor were broken into several lines.
I wonder if it is possible to automatically remove all line continuations in the whole code file?

Comment: Does you code now have physical line breaks or you just turned on the "Word wrap" option?

Comment: My code has CRLF line breaks now, not word wrapping.

Comment: I have found out that the line breaks were added by ReSharper installed on my pc, not by VS 2017 as I thought before. I turned off the ReSharper option as advised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043776/break-lines-and-wrapping-in-auto-formatting-of-visual-studio-with-resharper. As for my code, I corrected it manually removing every single line break in the file.